# Updating Product's Price Without Effecting Default Price in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, model-view-controller

I created one simple E-Commerce website. If I give an example from Amazon, like you see if you choose 128 GB price will be higher than 64 GB. So I want it my project too. I created some features for Laptop like RAM, SSD etc. When someone clicked 512 GB SSD (default is 256 GB) in the shopping cart price will be 100 dollar higher.

[image]

But when I choose the any upgrade, default price effecting too. In the database price changing and when I build program again price higher.

This is my code:

```
    public RedirectToActionResult AddToShoppingCart(int productId, decimal equipmentPrice)
    {
        var selectedProduct = _productRepository.GetProductById(productId);


        if (selectedProduct != null)
        {
            selectedProduct.Price += equipmentPrice;
            _shoppingCart.AddToCart(selectedProduct);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone the default object and then modify the price of the cloned-obj.
Your code should be like:

```
if (selectedProduct != null)
{
    var clone = new Product()
    {
        Price = selectedProduct.Price,
        ...
    };
    clone.Price += equipmentPrice
    _shoppingCart.AddToCart(clone);
}
```

That's beacuse selectedProduct points to the default object, and so you're editing also the obj. contained in the database

Comment: Sorry but i recognize that now, this causes a problem that clone creating new products.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: When I create new product with name of clone, because of this clone is new product, I can see that on products list on database and UI. But I just want to update same product's price and don't want to changing default price. @Filippo Ferrario

Comment: So, if I understood, you don't want any clone of the original product.
What if in your product class you add another attribute that contains the base price?
This way you will have: 
    BasePrice -> Tells you the default price
    Price -> Tells you the actual price, so you modify this when you need it @XcellentEEE